# Extend SharePoint 2016 Group

Tags: sharepoint-server

I've a FBA wep Application
we add the registered users in external database, and to allow users to view the website we add them to SharePoint group.

The expected number of registered user will exceed 20 million.
Is there any solution to extend group or read permission from list(allows 30 million record)?

Answer (score 1):

Sharepoint group can have only 5000 users per group.

You will get severe performance issues when all users are added directly to a SharePoint group. One obvious manifestation is that the crawl stops working.

If you really need to give access to that amount of users, I recommend that you put those users in an AD group, and couple that group to the SharePoint groups.

Comment: excuse my lack of knowledge, 
can AD Group contain 20 million users?
Could you explain more?

Comment: For scalability, here is a link with the limits: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc756101(v=ws.10)